# Openshift, Tomcat 7, HTTPUrlConnection, javax.crypto.JceSecurity not found

Tags: openshift

I am trying to run a very basic set of rest endpoints on OpenShift running Tomcat 7.  My code is running a very basic HTTPUrlConnection test that is throwing an exception.

Code is this basic:

```
@GET
@Path("/basicTest")
public Response basicTest(@QueryParam("hostName") String hostName) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    Response response = null;

    try{
        URL urlObject = new URL( hostName );
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)urlObject.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( connection.getInputStream()));

        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            builder.append(inputLine);
        in.close();

        response = Response.status(200).entity(builder.toString()).build();
    } catch( Exception e){
        response = Response.status(200).entity(e.getMessage()).build();
    }

    return response;
}
```

This runs just fine locally in Eclipse running Tomcat 7 and Java 7 on my Mac using either an HTTP or HTTPS URL. Against openshift HTTP works, but HTTPS I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.crypto.JceSecurity
javax.crypto.KeyAgreement.getInstance(KeyAgreement.java:178)
sun.security.ssl.JsseJce.getKeyAgreement(JsseJce.java:285)
sun.security.ssl.JsseJce.isEcAvailable(JsseJce.java:198)
sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$KeyExchange.isAvailable(CipherSuite.java:376)
sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite.isAvailable(CipherSuite.java:194)
sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.getApplicableCipherSuiteList(SSLContextImpl.java:338)
sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.getDefaultCipherSuiteList(SSLContextImpl.java:296)
sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.init(SSLSocketImpl.java:595)
sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:530)
sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:73)
sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.createSocket(HttpsClient.java:405)
sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:162)
sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:934)
sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1302)
sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
jim.controller.UberController.basicTest(UberController.java:69)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1511)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1442)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
jim.servlet.RequestFilter.doFilter(RequestFilter.java:28)
```

I also have a test endpoint that dumps all of the OpenShift system properties.

http://www.jimflath.com/APITest/rest/jvmStat/details

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: I'm not sure how, but my problem randomly cleared up after I stopped/started the application.

Comment: I heard it is associated with a corrupt java installation so that could be it

Comment: your solution worked. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the **same problem changing my connections from http to https** works fine locally but on openshift all response for creating an account (email confirmation using mail gun) failed to render proper response to user:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.crypto.JceSecurity
    javax.crypto.KeyAgreement.getInstance(KeyAgreement.java:179)
    sun.security.ssl.JsseJce.getKeyAgreement(JsseJce.java:286)
    sun.security.ssl.JsseJce.isEcAvailable(JsseJce.java:199)
    sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$KeyExchange.isAvailable(CipherSuite.java:376)
    sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite.isAvailable(CipherSuite.java:194)
    sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.getApplicableCipherSuiteList(SSLContextImpl.java:338)
    sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.getDefaultCipherSuiteList(SSLContextImpl.java:296)
    sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.init(SSLSocketImpl.java:593)
    sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:557)
    sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:109)
    com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:361)
    com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:236)
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2020)
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:697)
    javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:364)
    javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:245)
    com.cvs.util.SendMail.sendAccountConfirmation(SendMail.java:54)
    com.cvs.controller.SignUp.doPost(SignUp.java:121)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

I checked a couple of solutions they all point to **corrupt java installation**, my conclusion was purely because of **hot deploy**, **restarting the application resolved the problem**.